# How to save fragment backstack between application restart?

Tags: android, android-fragments

There are options in my application which can be applied properly only after application restart, so I do restart my application like that:

```
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, 
        new Intent(getActivity().getIntent()), 0);

AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, intent);
System.exit(1);
```

All of the activities are restored. However, all added fragments are lost. How can I restore all fragments, so the user will see exactly the same place after application restart?

Comment: Looks like you need to manually pass you fragment backstack representation into Intent used to restart activity (above one).

Comment: only manually saving states of your Fragments into some list, and saving it somewhere.